# On Factors, Modular sums and Cumulative sums

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We compute for $k \ge 2$,

$$
s_k \equiv {n(n+1) \over 2} \bmod{k} \tag 1
$$

$$
c_{k} = c_{k-1} + s_k \tag 2
$$

The RHS in Eqn. (1) can be readily recognized as the sum of first $n$ natural numbers, modulo $k$.

Eqn. (2) computes the ordinary cumulative sum of the modular sums $s_k$.

There seems to be a pattern where a factor of $n$ can be detected:

1. at an even step $k$.
2. $k$ is smaller than the smallest factor of $n$.

Is this a known phenomena? Can we say anything about the number of steps $k$ in which we can detect a factor?

Here are a few examples:

**Table for $8017 \times 31$:**
[image: Table for 8017 x 31]

**Table for $103 \times 257$:**
[image: Table for 8017 x 31]

**Table for $307 \times 439$**
[image: Table for 307 x 439]

Comment: Could you say in which framework you have become interested in such a question ?

Comment: I am just curious about integer and prime factorization. So, this is just conjecture and I could be totally wrong.

Comment: Have a look on MDPI site at this article 
"Structure of Triangular Numbers Modulo m" by Ulness.